# Location services. Not getting the first fix if minTime is greater than 15 minutes

Tags: android, gps

This is a very strange behaviour. If I have something like this (time interval set to 30 minutes):

```
mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,30 * 60 * 1000,100,mLocationListener);
```

My first fix takes forever and sometimes I don't get it at all (I waited for about 20 minutes) However if I choose a smaller interval for the time (30 seconds) I get it right away.

I thought that the values minTime and minDistance are only for getting new consecutive updates, and it wouldn't affect the first fix. I should get the first fix as soon as it's available. Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest to use two locationManagers, one as you are already doing for long-term updates, and another to get the first fix. Then you can unregister the second one as soon as you get the callback from it.
I heard of this pattern from Reto Meier and it's called "back-off" location. We are using it in mixare with the coarse location manager to get the first fix, and the GPS to get more precise infos. You can check the code here: https://github.com/mixare/mixare/blob/master/src/org/mixare/MixContext.java starting at line 150 (more or less)

HTH,
Daniele

Answer (score 0):

You may check, if well-known 3rd party GPS tools (like [GPS Status](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.eclipsim.gpsstatus2&hl=en)) have problems as well, or there is something with your code.

Please keep in mind that satellite visibility -- and therefore GPS signal quality -- may change quickly and first fix in a few days may take substantially longer than usual.